# How do I add favicons to my site?

Tags: xhtml, favicon, bookmarks

How can I populate my bookmarks with favicons like IE does when you click add bookmark.  Here is a snapshot of my web application - Facebook and Twitter have been added but no favicon.

Comment: this could have been discovered with a very quick trip to Google.

Comment: like this ... <img src="example.com/favicon" onerror="fetch_generic()" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE is simply fetching `example.com/favicon.ico`. If it's present, it's added to the bookmark. If not, the IE logo icon is.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon